# Create a DIV and give it a data-cart-info attribute. Inside the DIV, create a HEADING with mdc-typography--headline4" as its CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, heading

Create a DIV and give it a data-cart-info attribute. Inside the DIV, create a HEADING with mdc-typography--headline4" as its CSS class.

My Solution:

```
<div data-cart-info="mdc-typography--headline4">
   <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Please is my solution correct?

```
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-cart-info="mdc-typography--headline4"><h1>Heading</h1></div>
    <script>
      const supportedCards = {
        visa : 'visa', mastercard : 'mastercard'
      };
     </script>
```

I am building a PayCard(Credit Card Validator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my code

```
<div data-cart-info>
    <header class="mdc-typography--headline4"></header>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some comments as to how your code answers the question in order to improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, because from the requirement sentence, the *heading* (the `<h1>`) is supposed to have the class, not the div:

```
<div data-cart-info><h1 class="mdc-typography--headline4">Heading</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the statement the (data-cart-info) should be the attribute of the div then then your heading [h1] should have class (mdc-typography--headline4) 
Your code should be:

```
<div data-cart-info>
<h1 class="mdc-typography--headline4"></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```html
<div data-cart-info>
   <heading class="mdc-typography--headline4"></heading>
</div>
```